# javascript in jquery not working until refresh

Tags: ajax

I'm having a jquery mobile page with JavaScript inside. the problem is the JavaScript doesn't work unless the page is refreshed. here is my code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var url = window.location.search.substring(1);

    jQuery(function($){
        $('#mydiv').load('real_news.asp?'+url);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the URL inside jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($){
  var url = window.location.search.substring(1);

  $('#mydiv').load('real_news.asp?'+url);
});
```

Comment: still doesn't work till i refresh the page

Comment: have you closed your script tag properly

Comment: yes? here's my code:<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

   jQuery(function($){
  var url = window.location.search.substring(1);
  $('#mydiv').load('real_news.asp?'+url);
});
   
</script>

Comment: There might be some other reason behind it. Can you please provide your complete code in html file.